# Java Mongodb Update or Insert with _id

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

We need to insert below document to mongodb using Java MongoDB driver and below are the details:

insert {_id="20190304", val1="data1"}

-if there is already document in the collection with _id="20190304", then append the data (val1="data1") to the document , it should preserve the previous data

- If there is no document in the collection, with with _id="20190304", insert the document {_id="20190304", val1="data1"}
- So if collection has a document  {_id="20190304", val1="data1"} and if we insert new document with same _id {_id="20190304", valnew="data2"}, then it should append the extra fields i.e. it should be  {_id="20190304", val1="data1", valnew="data2"}

Comment: have you tried using the $set operator along with upsert=true?
Test something like: update({_id: yourid}, {$set: {val1="data1"}}, upsert=true)

Answer (score 0):

For the 2 first cases, you just do an update operation with the upsert value set to true (or an upsert operation if you are using MongoRepository).

The last case that you mention is impossible, as it collides with the first one: you can not do an insert if there is already an entity with the same id.